# Why does "Like Harps, Like Harps" end with "Lament..."?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection, pavlo-tychyna

The poem *Like Harps, Like Harps* (from *Pavlo Tychyna: The Complete Early Poetry Collection*) by Pavlo Tychnya is as follows:

> Like harps, like harps -
> the golden groves resounded
> Selfstrumming:
> spring is coming
> Fragrant,
> Adorned
> With flower-pearls
> With thoughts, with thoughts-
> The azure overflowed like the sea with ships
> Tender-toned:
> There will be fiery
> Battle!
> **There will be laughter, mother of pearl
>
> Lament.**
> I will stop and gaze about -
> Rivulets everywhere like chimes, a golden lark
> Undulating:
> Spring in full bloom
> Bountiful,
> Adorned
> With flower-pearls.
> My love, my dearest -
> Whether you walk forlorn, or filled with brimming happiness
> There beyond the fileds:
> O, open up
> The wheat husk of eyelashes:
> **There will be laughter, and mother-of-pearl
>
> Lament...**
> *1914*

Why is "laughter" and "mother of pearl" followed by "lament" twice in this poem?

Comment: in original it's "...laughing, weeping..." and "of pearls" on the next line. Let's say "pearl-like weeping"? Try google-translate the analysis of this poem https://zno.if.ua/?p=2577.

Comment: not "of pearls", maybe the right word is "pearlescent"